# How to execute and save result of an OS command to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

In python 2.7, I would like to execute an OS command (for example 'ls -l' in UNIX) and save its output to a file. I don't want the execution results to show anywhere else other than the file.

Is this achievable without using os.system?

Comment: What do you mean "hide the execution results from stdout"?  Do you just want those results to go into a file and not show up on the screen/other place in your program?

Comment: @eric Indeed, I don't want the results to show up on the screen or anywhere else other than the file.

Comment: Do you want to redirect just standard output or both standard output and standard error  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_call` redirecting stdout to a file object:

```
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    try:
        check_call(['ls', '-l'], stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.message)
```

Whatever you what to do when the command returns a non-zero  exit status should be handled in the except. If you want a file for stdout and another to handle stderr open two files:

```
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT, CalledProcessError, call

with open("stdout.txt","w") as f, open("stderr.txt","w") as f2:
    try:
        check_call(['ls', '-l'], stdout=f, stderr=f2)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to run a command have its output go into a file, you could use the `subprocess` module like

```
subprocess.call( "ls -l > /tmp/output", shell=True )
```

though that will not redirect `stderr`

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file and pass it to `subprocess.call` as the `stdout` parameter and the output destined for `stdout` will go to the file instead.

```
import subprocess

with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"], stdout=f)
```

It wont catch any output to `stderr` though that would have to be redirected by passing a file to `subprocess.call` as the `stderr` parameter. I'm not certain if you can use the same file.